# "ListPlot" of some probability distribution of a function under "NSum"

Tags: plotting, summation, iterators

Sir,
While trying to Listplot the Probability distribution of a function under command NSum, it shows some error messages and no plot is shown.
the details of the inputs written in mathematica along with the error message isgiven below.

```
 a[w0_, w1_] := ((w0^2 - w1^2)/w0^2)^(1/2)
    E0[h_, w0_, w1_, wz_, n_, s_, 
      j_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := (n + 1/2)*
       h*(w0 + \[CapitalOmega]) + (n - (n - s) + 1/2)*
       h*(w0 - \[CapitalOmega]) + (j + 1/2) h*wz
    Z0[h_, w0_, w1_, wz_, n_, s_, j_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Beta]_] := 
     NSum[Exp[-\[Beta]*((n + 1/2)*
           h*(w0 + \[CapitalOmega]) + (n - (n - s) + 1/2)*
           h*(w0 - \[CapitalOmega]) + (j + 1/2) h*wz)], {n, 0, 10}, {s, 0,
        50}, {j, 0, 10}]
f[h_, w0_, w1_, wz_, n_, s_, j_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 Exp[-\[Beta]*E0[h, w0, w1, wz, n, s, j, \[CapitalOmega]]]/
 Z0[h, w0, w1, wz, n, s, j, \[CapitalOmega], \[Beta]]
e[h_, w0_, w1_, n_, s_] := (n - (n - s) + 1) h (w1 - w0)
g[w0_, w1_, wz_, n_, s_, j_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Tau]_] := 
 Exp[(-I ((2 n - (n - s) + 1)*
      w0*\[Tau]*(2 + 
        Sqrt[(1 - (a[w0, w1])^2)] (2 + (a[w0, w1])^2))))/(
   3*(a[w0, w1])^2)]*
  Exp[(-I*\[Tau])/6*(
     4 (1 - (1 - (a[w0, w1])^2)^(3/2))*(w0*(2*n - (n - s) + 1)))/(a[
       w0, w1])^2 - 6 ((n - s)*\[CapitalOmega] + (j + 1/2) wz)]
P[h_, w0_, w1_, wz_, W_, n_, s_, 
  j_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Beta]_, \[Tau]_] := 
 DiracDelta[W - e[h, w0, w1, n, s]]*
  f[h, w0, w1, wz, n, s, 
   j, \[CapitalOmega], \[Beta]]*(Abs[
    g[w0, w1, wz, n, s, j, \[CapitalOmega], \[Tau]]])^2
ListPlot[Table[
  NSum[P[1, 10, 15, 5, W, n, s, j, 11, 0.01, 10], {n, 0, 10}, {s, 0, 
    50}, {j, 0, 10}], {W, 0, 20}], PlotRange -> Full]
```

The error message:

```
 NSum::itraw: Raw object 0 cannot be used as an iterator.
    
    NSum::itraw: Raw object 0 cannot be used as an iterator.
    
    NSum::itraw: Raw object 0 cannot be used as an iterator.
    
    General::stop: Further output of NSum::itraw will be suppressed during this calculation.
    
    NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) P[1,10,15,5,W,n,s,j,11,0.01,<<1>>] is not numerical at point j = 0.
    
    NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) P[1.,10.,15.,5.,W,n,s,j,11.,0.01,<<1>>] is not numerical at point j = 0.`.
    
    NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) NSum[P[1,10,15,5,W,n,s,j,11,0.01,<<1>>],{j,0,10},{WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision,NSumTerms->15,Method->Automatic,AccuracyGoal->\[Infinity],PrecisionGoal->Automatic,VerifyConvergence->True,Compiled->Automatic,EvaluationMonitor->None,NSumExtraTerms->Automatic,WynnDegree->1}] is not numerical at point s = 0.
General::stop: Further output of NSum::nsnum will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Would you kindly suggest me how can I correct the inputs such that I can get the desired Plot.
Thanking you in advance....

Comment: Wrong syntax in ListPlot: ListPlot[Table[...],, PlotRange -> Full]]. ListPlot has no iterator.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your reply... If you suggest me the correct syntax, which isapplicable in this case. I tried using simple Plot (without using Table) as there is a diracdelta function but there was also some error messages.

Comment: `Plot[DiracDelta[x], {x, -1, 1}]`should work, but you do not see the infinitely thin peak.

Comment: Ok...Sir...Then, can it be done by plotting discrete points, such as List PLot or Discrete Plot

Comment: That is right. Or you could define your own function like: `f[x_] := If[Abs[x] < 10^-2, 1, 0];
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Red]`

Comment: Ok Sir...Thank you again for your kind response...